# Getting error while looping through dataset

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I'm using VS 2012 C#. I'm trying to loop through datasets to get information from an Access database. I have a combobox that when an item is selected it should print out all the data for  that given scenario. For some the the values in the combobox I get the error, "The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'." But for some of the other values I don't and the information is retrieved without an issue. Here is all the necessary code,

```
con2.Open();
ad2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con2);
ad2.Fill(ds2, "AC_SCENARIO");
con2.Close()

try
{
    string end = "ENDDATE";
    string start = "START";

    foreach (DataRow drRow in ds2.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= ds2.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            string qual0 = ds2.Tables["AC_SCENARIO"].Rows[i]["QUAL0"].ToString();
            string qual1 = ds2.Tables["AC_SCENARIO"].Rows[i]["QUAL1"].ToString();
            string qual2 = ds2.Tables["AC_SCENARIO"].Rows[i]["QUAL2"].ToString();
            string qual3 = ds2.Tables["AC_SCENARIO"].Rows[i]["QUAL3"].ToString();
            string qual4 = ds2.Tables["AC_SCENARIO"].Rows[i]["QUAL4"].ToString();

            //HERE IS A SAMPLE QUERY 
            if (qual0 != null && (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem == qual0)
            {
                ad.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT b.RSV_CAT, b.SEQNUM, b.LEASE,  b.WELL_ID, a.QUALIFIER, a.KEYWORD, a.EXPRESSION FROM [AC_ECONOMIC] a INNER JOIN [AC_PROPERTY] b on a.PROPNUM=b.PROPNUM WHERE a.KEYWORD = '" 
                + end + "' AND (a.QUALIFIER = '" + qual0 + "' OR a.QUALIFIER IS NULL) AND NOT a.EXPRESSION Like '%[/@]%'", con);
            }

            ds.Clear();
            ad.Fill(ds); //The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'. 
            //ERROR OCCURS HERE

            con.Open();
            ad.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

EDIT: HERE IS THE con CODE

```
        String filePath = textBox1.Text;

        con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath);
```

I have more queries such as those listed for another dataset and then I merge the two datasets together and output them to a datagridview. The error occurs on the line ad.Fill(ds); If anyone can explain this issue to me or has any help that would be great.

Comment: You have debugged this, *right*? You've verified, *through the debugger*, that it's entering that `if` block... *right*?

Comment: have you verified this line `ad.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT b.RSV_CAT, b.SEQNUM, b.LEASE,  b.WELL_ID, a.QUALIFIER, a.KEYWORD, a.EXPRESSION FROM [AC_ECONOMIC] a INNER JOIN [AC_PROPERTY] b on a.PROPNUM=b.PROPNUM WHERE a.KEYWORD = '" 
                + end + "' AND (a.QUALIFIER = '" + qual0 + "' OR a.QUALIFIER IS NULL) AND NOT a.EXPRESSION Like '%[/@]%'", con);`

Comment: @DJKRAZE well if it works for some of the selected values in the combobox it should be verified

Answer (score 1):

Columns collection of `DataTable` is *zero based index* and is one less then `Count`, the loop should be one less then number of columns as first column is at `0` index and last column is columns `count-1`. You can use `<` instead of `<=` in loop condition to iterate from `zero` to `Count-1`.

*Change*

```
for (int i = 0; i <= ds2.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
```

*To*

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds2.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
```

**Creation of con is also not present in the code you have in OP**

Comment: Call Fill method after ExecuteNonQuery, also check the query if it is getting record.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure that it is because once I put the Fill method after the ExecuteNonQuery it gives me the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 1):

the problem is probably here

```
 if (qual0 != null && (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem == qual0)
```

In some scenarios the if loop turns out to be true and ad.SelectCommand will get initialized.

**EDIT**
Are you sure the Select Command is forming correctly for every values of qual0.
Please try using named parameters while forming the query . the qual variable might be having some `'` in it that prevent your query getting formed correctly..

**EDIT**

```
qual0.Replace("'","\"");
```

Comment: How would you suggest I remedy it?

Comment: can you just try putting qual0.Replace("'","\"") as first statement inside the if block.

Answer (score 0):

You've not provided a default case for if `qual0` is null.

I'm going to assume that you do this multiple times and it's not just the one `qual` variable you check and build a statement for, if that's the case then you might be better off refactoring to something like this:

```
if (qual0 != null && (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem == qual0)
{
    ad.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT b.RSV_CAT, b.SEQNUM, b.LEASE,  b.WELL_ID, a.QUALIFIER, a.KEYWORD, a.EXPRESSION FROM [AC_ECONOMIC] a INNER JOIN [AC_PROPERTY] b on a.PROPNUM=b.PROPNUM WHERE a.KEYWORD = '" 
                       + end + "' AND (a.QUALIFIER = '" + qual0 + "' OR a.QUALIFIER IS NULL) AND NOT a.EXPRESSION Like '%[/@]%'", con);
}

if (ad.SelectCommand != null)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ad.SelectCommand.CommandText))
    {
        ds.Clear();
        ad.Fill(ds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `if (ad.SelectCommand != null) { if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ad.SelectCommand.CommandText) { //code here } }`, will update answer.

Comment: For some reason I'm still getting the same error and when I get rid of the ds.Clear(); and ad.Fill(ds); outside of your if statements it gives me 'object is not set to an instance of the object, if that helps

Comment: Ok well that's me out of ideas other than stepping through the code in the debugger line-by-line to find out why it's null.